# Получение access token vk. Django

Tags: django, vkontakte-api

Суть такова: сделать так называемую привязку VK с целью получения access token. Зашел в документацию VK - нашел инфу:[image: Документация VK API]

Я пытаюсь делать запрос, выдается ошибка:
{
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "client_id is undefined"
}
Так же сначала попробовал сделать авторизацию через VK, думая, что так смогу получить access token(не знаю, можно ли так действительно получить), и у меня вроде получилось реализовать авторизацию, и ошибок о client_id не было.
Вопрос таков: Правильно ли сама мысль о получении access token(имеется в виду, делается ли это действительно так, как я задумал или же все в корне не верно)? Если нет, то как это можно реализовать, если да, то где ошибки? Код ниже

**views.py Перенаправление на vk**

```
@login_required
def vk_link(request):
    return redirect('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token/', params={
        'client_id': 'id',
        'client_secret': 'token',
        'redirect_url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile',
        'code': request.GET.get('code'),
    })
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^login', views.login, name="login"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name="main"),
    path('signUp', views.signUp, name="signUp"),
    path('profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('logout', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('vk', views.vk_link, name="vk"),
]
```

**кнопка перенаправления**

```
<a href="{% url 'vk' %}">
    <img src="" alt="vk">
</a>
```

id и secret заменил по понятным причинам

**EDIT**
Правильно ли я передаю параметры при redirect? Может быть в этом проблема? Видел, как параметры ещё передают через urlencode(),но с ним у меня тоже не получилось, ошибка та же

**Скрин ошибки**
[image: Ошибка при переходе на ссылку]

Comment: Я верно понимаю, эта ошибка появляется при `redierct`. Не до конца понимаю, где именно возникает указанная вами ошибка

Comment: Да, возникает при redirect. Происходит перенаправление на ссылку, где появляется словарь, который я написал в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил скрин ошибки

Comment: Я понял, в чём ваша ошибка. Подождите немного, сейчас оформлю подробный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы делаете `redirect("...", params={...})`, то параметры, как я правильно помню, никуда не попадают. Это можно исправить, если их добавить вручную к url запроса используя `urllib.parse`

Решение будет выглядеть так:

```py
from urllib import parse

...

@login_required
def vk_link(request):
    return redirect(
        'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token/?' + parse.urlencode({
            'client_id': 'id',
            'client_secret': 'token',
            'redirect_url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile',
            'code': request.GET.get('code'),
        })
    )
```

---

Ответ с английского StackOverflow: *[Add params to given URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506425/17349246)*

Comment: Да, параметры действительно передаются, однако теперь при redirect ошибка 404 Not found. Как я вижу, я не получаю code, т.е. передается None. Не подскажите, как его получить?

Comment: Сейчас пересмотрел вопрос, сделал небольшую и очень глупую опечатку. Я забыл добавить знак вопроса. Теперь должно всё работать

Comment: Теперь почти работает) Выдается ошибка о том, что code неправильный. В параметрах передается code=None, то есть его нет просто. Значит 'code' = request.Get.get('code') не возвращает код. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его можно получить?

Comment: Честно, не знаю. Может сервер возвращает ошибку вместо кода, см [документация](https://dev.vk.com/api/access-token/authcode-flow-user#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20code)

Comment: Хорошо, в любом случае спасибо, покапаюсь ещё на счет code